# compare dates in SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I would like to compare today's date with the dates I'm pulling from a DB and select entries accordingly. Those two formats do not match (I assume so) and I get an error. By the way, I am not sure what exact format myDate is stored in.  Below is what I would essentially like to achieve.

```
WHERE (myDate > CURDATE())
```

Comment: try just returning the whole data set (without any WHERE clause) with those two values side - by - side. It might give you a better idea of what's wrong: 

SELECT mydate, CURDATE() as CurdateFn FROM ...

Comment: Can you post the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

select * from mytable where
convert(date, myDate) > convert(date,myDate)

in sql server.

or, if that does not work, try formatting the date with substring and then converting/casting/parsing.

select convert(date, (substring(myfield,9,2) + '/' + substring(myfield,6,2) + '/' + substring(myfield,1,4))) from mytable

Answer (score 0):

you can format both the dates as below .

`select * from mytable where convert(char(8), myDate,112) > convert(char(8),myDate,112)`

code 112 will case them to be converted in YYYYMMDD format

Comment: I tried all these, but to no avail. I get "error in WHERE clause", nothing specific..

Comment: @mvaitkus can you put the whole query which you are executing ?

Comment: Below is the line that I currently use and it works:    `(ITEM.DUE_DATE >= {d '2015-07-01'})`. If I replace it with `(ITEM.DUE_DATE >= CURDATE())` it does not. Or maybe I'm not using it right..

Comment: I get error saying my date format should be yyyy-mm-dd. But I tried everything to convert it..